# pecl instal ibm_db2 fails

Tags: db2, db2-connect

I need to install ibm_db2 extension for making php connection with db2. So I have used pecl. But it produces error.

```
$ pecl install ibm_db2
```

When I run this, the below error occurs.

```
.....
checking      in /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64...
checking      in /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib32... found
checking for DB2 CLI include files in default path... checking in /home/db2inst1/sqllib... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the DB2 CLI distribution
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/ibm_db2/configure --with-IBM_DB2=/home/db2inst1/sqllib' failed
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

1. download `ibm_data_server_driver_for_odbc_cli_linuxx64_v97.tar.gz` from ibm.com
2. `untar` the file into: `/opt/ibm/`
3. enter command > pecl install ibm_db2 
   When prompted for DB2 Installation Directory, use: `/opt/ibm/odbc_cli/clidriver/`

Answer (score 2):

You need the DB2 headers to build the ibm_db2 PHP extension. They are included in the [IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878&wv=1).

Answer (score 1):

before install ibm_db2, you have install expc, in the folder uncompress execute the script db2_install with root user: # ./db2_install

It asks for the installation path (e /opt/ibm/db2)

then install ibm_db2

Answer (score 1):

Install a DB2 instance (On Ubuntu due to following instructions: http://www.db2teamblog.com/2010/09/db2-express-c-packages-for-ubuntu-1004.html) This will work also on newer systems.

After that run the following command:

```
pecl install ibm_db2
```

When prompted type:

```
/opt/ibm/dbs/V9.7/
```

and confirm the installation directory

Comment: do you know how to pass the path to avoid prompt?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because in the path `/home/db2inst1/sqllib` not found the include folder.

you must download `db2exc_974_LNX_x86_64.tar.gz`, uncompress it `(e. /otp/ibm/db2)`

then install pecl install ibm_db2

DB2 Installation Directory? use this : `/opt/ibm/db2`

Answer (score 0):

Check also the first comment on PHP manual by Jean Ferreira.

[link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need the APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT TOOLS when you install the client you should have the option to install them.

Check your `/home/db2inst1/sqllib/include` folder you'll see that you only have asn.h, a boatload of files is missing when you don't have the development tools installed.

Then use `/home/db2inst1/sqllib` as your install directory.

Answer (score 0):

I lacked the APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS in my DB2 installation (confirmed by only having asn.h in my includes folder)

**To install the APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS into an existing DB2 installation, follow these instructions**

1. Check your product information. You will need this information later.
   `db2ls -p -q -b /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5`
2. Download the appropriate Universal Fix Pack from IBM:
   https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Information%2BManagement&product=ibm/Information+Management/DB2&release=All&platform=Linux+64-bit,x86_64&function=textSearch&text=universal

   - Be sure to find the matching FixPack version (from the step above) and the correct architecture.
   - Save the file to `/opt/ibm/fixpack`
3. Gunzip/Tar the file
   `cd /opt/ibm/fixpack`
   `gunzip /opt/ibm/fixpack/downloaded_pack.tar.gz`
   `tar xvf /top/ibm/fixpack/downloaded_pack.tar`
4. Create a response file `/opt/ibm/fixpack/devtools.resp` like this.
   Replace the PROD value with the Product Response File ID
   Replace the FILE value with the DB2 installation folder

   `PROD                        = DB2_SERVER_EDITION
   FILE                        = /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5
   LIC_AGREEMENT               = ACCEPT
   INSTALL_TYPE                = CUSTOM
   COMP                        = APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS`
5. Stop DB2 with `db2stop` or `db2stop force`
6. Run db2setup with the response code
   `cd /opt/ibm/fixpack/universal/`
   `./db2setup -r /opt/ibm/fixpack/devtools.resp`
7. Start DB2 with `dbstart`
8. When you are done, run 
   `pecl install ibm_db2`
   Use `/home/db2inst1/sqllib` as your install directory.

---

Original instructions were found here to install them into an existing DB2 installation (I used the 3rd option):
http://db2commerce.com/2014/02/11/installing-a-db2-component-after-the-rest-of-db2-is-installed/

Answer (score -1):

I got solution for the above issue.

Need to select Custom Install while installing db2. So I just uninstalled and reinstalled DB2.

After that It works fine for me. Thanks everyone :)